# Collections.sort won't work with custom comparator?

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

```
import java.util.*;

public class ABC {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> values = null;

        values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(5);
        values.add(9);
        values.add(3);
        values.add(55);
        values.add(4);

        Collections.sort(values);
        System.out.println(values);



        values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        values.add(5);
        values.add(9);
        values.add(3);
        values.add(55);
        values.add(4);

        Comparator<Integer> cmp = new Comparator<Integer>() {
                    @Override
                    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
                        int o1i = o1;
                        int o2i = o2;
                        return o1i - o1i;
                    }
                };

        Collections.sort(values, cmp);
        System.out.println(values);
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
[3, 4, 5, 9, 55]
[5, 9, 3, 55, 4]
```

which is obviously not the expected result. What am I missing?

Comment: Your `compare` method always returns 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a bug:

Change

```
return o1i - o1i;
```

to

```
return o1i - o2i;
```

Comment: Thanks. and to think I've read it 3 times before submitting :)

Comment: That's one of those great "clever programming tricks" that should only be used if you know what you're doing - and not at all for languages without an unsigned type (well for ints you can still cast to long which will work). Except it is intended that Integer.MAX_VALUE < Integer.MIN_VALUE :p Probably one of the most often seen bugs in custom comparators in java

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator is subtracting `o1i - o1i`, giving you 0 each time.

(You aren't gaining anything by assigning `o1` and `o2` to local `int` variables either; just subtract `o1 - o2`.)

Comment: That's mostly done to allow placing a breakpoint at the problematic line.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typing error, the comperator should have `return o1i - o2i;`

and not `return o1i - o1i;`

Answer (score 0):

```
return o1i - o1i;
```

I guess you meant;

```
return o1i - o2i;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
int o1i = o1;
                    int o2i = o2;
                    return o1i - o2i;
```

This gives following result

```
[3, 4, 5, 9, 55]
```

[3, 4, 5, 9, 55]